# Create Link Button with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'd like to use JQuery to create a link button, but the code I wrote below doesn't seem to work. What is missing?

```
<head>
        <title>Click Url</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"     
        type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {
                    $("#Button1").click(function() {
                        $("#an1").click();
                    });
                });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://google.com" id="an1">Click</a>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

The `click()` method will not work on hyperlinks. Instead of `$("#an1").click();` to redirect to that URL, use this:

```
window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
```

Or, as suggested by davidsleeps in the comments, do this:

```
window.location.href = $("#an1").attr("href");
```

Comment: maybe you could make it: window.location.href = $("#an1").attr("href");

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking the links onclick event, which doesn`t have anything bound to it.

The fact that you transfer to a url when you click a link is browser behavior and has nothing to do with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this code would make it work, but again you're just firing the click event. You're not actually simulating a click.

```
$('#an1').click(function(){
  window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

Now when you fire the click event it will actually change the location.